# Subtracting dates using date()

Tags: php, mysql, date

I am wondering how can I do this: Subtract two different dates that are obtained trough the date method. Basically, it is for a game I am making that requires a certain amount of time to perform an action. So let's say the user clicks a button, a query is executed sending the current time of the moment the user clicked to the database, and later on, I plan on being able to display the amount of time remaining for the action to complete.

Here's a "sketch":

```
$currenttime = date("d:m:Y \H:i:s");

$datetobeinsertedindatabase = $currenttime + 1 HOUR; //The entry on the database will have +1 Hour than the time the user clicked (I don't know how to do this part) 

mysqli_prepare($link,"INSERT INTO(...)"); //Inserting the time to the database - this part I know how to do.

//DISPLAYING THE TIME LEFT SOMEWHERE ELSE

mysqli_prepare($link,"SELECT (...)"); //Selecting the time from the database and bind it to a varaible - lets say "$test" (I can also do this)

$currenttime = date("d:m:Y \H:i:s");

//This is where I get blocked: How do I subtract the updated time on the database to the $currenttime and display it's difference.
```

Resume of the points I'm having trouble with:

- Not sure if `date("d:m:Y \H:i:s");` is well formatted.
- How to add 1 Hour to the current time.
- Subtracting the updated time on the database to the current time.

I did search for multiple questions here on stackoverflow and some other websites but all I could find was examples where the dates weren't generated with date() it was something like (May, 3rd 2016).

Thank You in advance

Comment: Too many questions here and all them have been asked and answered at [so]. Take your time to search and you will find them.

Comment: Thanks, I will keep searching, but if you find one let me know :)

Comment: @Syvered I didn't understand your third point clearly, you want to subtract $test with current time() ?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Not sure if date("d:m:Y \H:i:s"); is well formatted.

  change to this formate `date("Y-m-d H:i:s")`, because **MySQL** retrieves and displays **DATETIME** values in **YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS** format & also easy to convert to `strtotime()`
- How to add 1 Hour to the current time.

  following code will add 1 hour to current time

  `$currenttime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
  $datetobeinsertedindatabase = strtotime("+60 minutes", strtotime($currenttime));
  $datetobeinsertedindatabase = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $datetobeinsertedindatabase);`
- Subtracting the updated time on the database to the current time.

  assume time which is retrieving from mysql is in this formate **YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS** & stored in `$test` variable and code for subtraction will be below

  `$test = date_create("2017-01-18 13:38:06");
  $currenttime = date_create(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
  $diff = date_diff($test, $currenttime);`

difference will be stored in `$diff` object and output will be below

```
<code>DateInterval Object
(
    [y] => 0
    [m] => 0
    [d] => 0
    [h] => 0
    [i] => 1
    [s] => 20
    [weekday] => 0
    [weekday_behavior] => 0
    [first_last_day_of] => 0
    [invert] => 0
    [days] => 0
    [special_type] => 0
    [special_amount] => 0
    [have_weekday_relative] => 0
    [have_special_relative] => 0
)</code>
```

and take a look once [php date function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank You :)

Comment: hey sorry, some problem in posting the code and took to many editing

Answer (score 0):

Depend on MySQL. MySQL is available everywhere and has very convenient functions for almost everything. I will use plain text scripts in this answer, translation into mysqli will remain as an exercise.

I love Unix timestamps, calculations with 32-bit integers are fast and clear (to me), but you can use MySQL functions for dates-as-strings manipulation also. Do yourself a favor, install HeidiSQL and browse the **Date and Time Function** reference (<kbd>F1</kbd> inside DATE_ADD). You can use MySQL to obtain current time also.

Using integer timestamps:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2016-12-31 23:59:59')  --convert string to integer
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(59)              --convert integer to string
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME($integerTimestamp + 3600)  --adding an hour
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP()-$integerTimestamp     --how many seconds have elapsed?
```

Using datetime/string values:

```
SELECT DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
SELECT DATE_ADD('1970-01-01 23:59:59',INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

The same expressions are good for INSERT statements also.